# SQL Server Select value pairs from table if the value pair exists (as defined by a substring)

Tags: sql-server, substring, where-clause

How can I select a value pair from my table if a value equals another value with a sub string concatenated on? I have a SQL Server table that contains library scan cards, a mock-up is shown here.

```
Name            Status         Activation_Date
John_Doe        Active         1-1-2015
Jane_Smith      Inactive       2-2-2014
Jane_Smith_1    Active         1-2-2015
```

In this table, when a patron loses his/her card, the old card is deactivated, and a new card is created. The name is the primary key, so since the prior key is in use a "_1" suffix is added.

I would like my results to show the record for "Jane_Smith" and also "Jane_Smith_1".

Comment: This is very poor schema design. What happens when you have a 'John Smith' and 'John Smithson', where one real name matches the other of a different individual?

Comment: Or even more ridiculous what happens when you have John Smith and another person who has the same name gets a card? Does it become John_Smith_1? How do you know that isn't the same John Smith?

Comment: And what happen if Jhon Lose his card 10 times? the sorting by string go crazy.

Comment: I have greatly simplified the schema design for clarification purposes. However, the suffix in question will ALWAYS be "_1" so basically, return all value pairs where one string ("John_Smith") is a substring of all but the final two characters of another string in the table ("John_Smith_1"). This rule will always be true.

Comment: OK let's assume this schema is workable. What are you expecting for output? The example you posted shows results for both Jane_Smith and Jane_Smith_1. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to return a list of all the rows where there exists another row in the table that matches the name but for the _1, how about something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable A
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE REPLACE(Name,'_1','') = REPLACE(A.Name,'_1','')
      AND Name <> A.Name
)
```

Comment: Thank you Benjamin! This is exactly what I wanted. Works very well!